# How to change the endpoint of prometheus metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus

I am trying to expose some metrics from a spring-boot service to prometheus.
Unfortunately, both spring-boot actuator and the prometheus simple-client expose their metrics through the */metrics* endpoint.

How can the endpoint of the simple-client be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the java client you specify the endpoint when setting up the servlet, see https://github.com/RobustPerception/java_examples/blob/master/java_simple/src/main/java/io/robustperception/java_examples/JavaSimple.java#L39 for example. You can change the endpoint to whatever you like.

Comment: With Spring-Boot you don't set the servlet yourself. It is created automagically if the prometheus jar is found on the classpath (I add it to gradle with compile('io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:0.0.14'). I don't see where the endpoint can be specified.

Comment: There must be something extra going on in your code, as nothing on the client_java end hardcodes to /metrics.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look at the Prometheus Java Simpleclient Spring Boot Metric it exposes prometheus metrics at the /prometheus endpoint.

Github Project: https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/tree/master/simpleclient_spring_boot

Maven Artifact: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_spring_boot

On your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_spring_boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

In your springboot configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        DefaultExports.initialize();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MetricsServlet(), "/prometheus");
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBootMetricsCollector springBootMetricsCollector(Collection<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics) {
        SpringBootMetricsCollector springBootMetricsCollector = new SpringBootMetricsCollector(
            publicMetrics);
        springBootMetricsCollector.register();
        return springBootMetricsCollector;
    }
```

Comment: You can now also just add the dependency (`io.prometheus:simpleclient_spring_boot:0.0.19`) and use `@EnablePrometheusEndpoint` and `@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector` on your Boot app.

Comment: @DonovanMuller is this some kind of hidden feature? I can find absolutely no reference of `@EnablePrometheusEndpoint` and `@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector` on GitHub!

Comment: @HansKristian See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/issues/156

Answer (score 3):

You can change spring-boot actuator's endponit and leave `/metrics` to Prometheus.

Add following configurations to your `application.properties`:

```
endpoints.metrics.id=springmetrics
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=false
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
```

and you'll have a new endpoint `/springmetics` for spring actuator and `/metrics` for Prometheus.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set up these properties in your application.properties file:

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=
management.endpoints.web.base-path=
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually did the trick for me. Relevant documentation can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

Comment: This will change all endpoints under /actuator to be on root "/" and not just prometheus.